# In which global.asax events is the ADF claimstore available

Tags: ambient-data-framework, iis-and-asp.net

Maybe this is an ASP.NET beginner's question, but I could not find the answer on this site. I could get a ADF Claimstore object working only in the [HttpApplication.PreRequestHandlerExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.prerequesthandlerexecute.aspx) event.

In which [HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) events is the ADF claimstore expected to be available?

Answer (score 9):

It is not documented in which Web Application Event ADF should be executed. The recommendation would be to use an event that is executed before the Request Handler is executed and after the session data and cookies are available since they are mandatory for ADF. `HttpApplication.PreRequestHandlerExecute` is the right event for this.

Please note that ADF is executed as a Http Module that implements `IRequiresSessionState` and populates claims on `PreRequestHandlerExecute`

Sample Code:

```
public class HttpModule : IHttpModule, IRequiresSessionState {
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            application.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(this.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute);
        }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are not saying it explictly but I think this means there are no other HttpApplication events cause they are either to early or to late in the chain.